# Getting the scope within Angular UI tabs

Tags: tabs, angularjs, scope, angular-ui

I'm having some trouble with angular scopes within the context of a tab (Angular UI).

Here is my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/afrankel/ADukg/2227/) (slimmed down example showing fields on multiple tabs with a single submit button outside of the tabs).

Here is the basic html layout:

```
<form...>
  <tab>
    <pane>
      <input...>
    </pane>
  </tab>
</form>
```

Looking at the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/afrankel/ADukg/2227/), without the tabs if I submit a very basic form I would see the $scope.user be an object.   Since the fields are within panes (tabs) the scope is incorrect.   How can I get access to the submitted user object in createUser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772041/angualrjs-and-angular-ui-bootstrap-tabs-scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `user` model is buried deep within an isolate scope.  To get the code working as expected, you would need to `alert` out the value of `$scope.$$childHead.panes[0].$$nextSibling.user.first_name` not `$scope.user`.  This is obviously not a solution.

A simple solution is to add an empty `user` object to the controller scope.  The `ng-model` directives in your HTML will then bind to this property.  Your controller should look like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.createUser = function () {
    alert($scope.user);
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Makes perfect sense.

Comment: +1.  Note that in the OP's fiddle, the `user` object gets created on the directives' transcluded scopes (not the directives' isolate scopes).